# Display strings from array in a textboxes that are in different xaml WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've got a 10 element array and I want to display those elements in a 10 textboxes that are in different xaml file and are created as a child of stack panel.

How do I do it?

Comment: Some sample code would help immensely

Comment: Is the DataContext same for the all the xaml files and does it contain that 10 element array?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class.  Link both sets of XAML to the same fields in the same instance of the class.  Let DataBinding be your friend.